A symmetric affine connection is compatible with $g$ if it preserves length or angle of parallel vector fields.
Here is one of my homework:
Let $(M^n,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold, $\nabla$ be a symmetric affine connection. Show that $\nabla$ is a Riemannian connection if it satisfies one of the following conditions for any parallel vector fields $Y,Z$ along any curve $\gamma$:
(1) The length $\left\langle Y(\gamma(t)),Y(\gamma(t))\right\rangle$ is a constant.
(2) The cosine of the angle $$\frac{\left\langle Y(\gamma(t)),Z(\gamma(t)\right\rangle}{\sqrt{\left\langle Y(\gamma(t)),Y(\gamma(t))\right\rangle\cdot \left\langle Z(\gamma(t)),Z(\gamma(t))\right\rangle}}$$
is a constant.
Question 1: I think I can prove (1), here is the sketch. Take a linearly independent parallel vector fields $\{E_1,\dots,E_n\}$ along the integral curve of $X$, and then using the fact that $\left\langle E_i,E_j\right\rangle=const$ from (1) to deduce that
$$\begin{aligned}
&\left\langle \nabla_{X_p} Y, Z_p\right\rangle +\left\langle \nabla_{X_p} Z, Y_p\right\rangle\\
=&\left\langle \nabla_{X_p} Y^i E_i, Z^j(p) E_j|_p\right\rangle+\left\langle \nabla_{X_p} Z^j E_j, Y^i(p) E_i|_p\right\rangle\\
=&\left\langle X_p(Y^i) E_i|_p, Z^j(p) E_j|_p\right\rangle+\left\langle X_p(Z^j)E_j|_p, Y^i(p) E_i|_p\right\rangle\\
=& X_p(Y^iZ^j) \left\langle E_i|_p, E_j|_p\right\rangle\\
=& X_p(Y^iZ^j\left\langle E_i|_p, E_j|_p\right\rangle)=X_p(\left\langle X,Y \right\rangle)
\end{aligned} $$
Am I correct?
Question 2: I think (2) is wrong. For example, consider a symmetric, non-Riemannian connection on $\mathbb{R}^1$:
$$ \nabla_XY(t):= \big(x(t)\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}(y(t))-x(t)y(t)\big)\cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}|_t$$
which clearly preserves the angle of parallel vector fields.
Am I correct?
Any comments or correction are appreciated. THANKS!

Yes, the 2nd is wrong. Talk to your instructor about it.
